# how to remove DB using Arry String method DELETE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, extjs

i am tried to delete data from my DB using the ext.js script below: 
it seem to be working on the browser when i clicked on the icon "Delete" but when i clicked on some other toolbar tap some whereat the browser. it was reloaded with my same data on the row grid. I really don't know that i only delete only the Array but not delete the actual DB by sending wrong servers or methods. I don't know. I am tried using different method to delete it but it same problem came back.

Can anyone help me? I am new to ext.javascript or ext.Ajax ...etc..

codes:

```
var userHistoryGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: 880,
    height: 450, //autoHeight: true, collapsible: false, title: 'Employee\'s Request History', icon: 'images/newtodo1.png', store: userHistoryStore, multiSelect: false, columnLines: false, enableColumnHide: false, enableColumnMove: false, enableColumnResize: false, selType: 'rowmodel',

    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No prior requests',
        stripeRows: false,
        enableTextSelection: true,

        getRowClass: function (record) {
            return record.get('Status') == 'Approved' ? 'normal-row' : 'hilite-row';
        }
    },

    items: [{
        icon: 'images/delete.png',
        tooltip: 'Delete Request',
        handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            cellvalue = record.get('Delete');

            if (cellvalue != 'Delete') {
                Ext.MessageBox.confirm(
                    'Confirm Deletion',
                    'Delete this request?',

                function (btn) {
                    if (btn == 'yes') {

                        cellvalue = record.get('EventID');

                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'delUserHistoryGrid.asp',
                            async: false,
                            method: 'DELETE',
                            params: {
                                id: userHistoryStore
                            },
                            timeout: 30000,
                            success: function (result) {
                                userHistoryStore.reload();
                                userinfoStore.reload();
                            }
                        });

                        //delete userHistoryStore[rowIndex];
                        userHistoryStore.removeAt(rowIndex);
                        //eventStore.destroy(rowIndex);
                        //userHistoryStore.destroy(rowIndex);
                        //record.EventID.removeAt(grid);
                        userinfoStore.reload();
                    } else {
                        rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to help you pinpoint your issue:

1. Do not remove the record from the store after the ajax call. Only do it if it was succssful. Move `userHistoryStore.removeAt(rowIndex);` inside the success callback.
   I don't think `async: false` actually exists. So your ajax call returns immediately. You should continue the flow of execution in the callback.
2. Add a `failure` callback and check (breakpoint or log) the reponse you get. You should also check the response in the `success` case as there might be some message of interest there too. Depends on the service.
3. Use your browsers dev tools and check the network. You should first verify that the ajax call is executed succesfully and then that you receive a valid reply. Check the response code. If it's not in the 200s it's an error. You can search the web more once you see the response code you get.
4. Without knowing anything about your services or your app I think passing the whole store as your `id` param is probably wrong. Shouldn't you pass the `cellvalue`?

Comment: Thank you. I will try to check the web first, then adding your suggestions to my code n test it out. Hope it will work. I'm greatly appreciate your helps.